# into statement in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

when we use "into #temp" statement in the select query then why table structure or relations("Primary Key, Forgin Key") are not copied to SQL server?

Comment: If you are really asking "why", then the answer is "because this is how it was designed". If you want to know what to do about it, then see https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18059/5203.

Comment: If you want schema to be copied in to #temp table without data then do like this select * into #temp from dbo.MyTable WHERE 1=2

Comment: Yes. I know that.In this, we want to specify the where criteria for copying the schema..my question is that at the time of select statement instead of where 1=2. Example: - select * into #temp from tablename

Comment: Copying the foreign key would be highly undesirable. It would mean parent rows couldn't be deleted because some table in tempdb was present that still contained references. This is not what's wanted 99% of the time. When you *do* want constraints/indexes, you can create them yourself.